# Does GIF image scaling supported by iPhone Retina device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, retina-display

I have **abc.gif** Image with **single frame** which i have created in *MSPaint*. I have also kept **abc@2x.gif** image with **single frame**.

But my gif image is not getting scaled properly in iPhone Retina device and simulator.

Is there any issue with this??  I have read on Apple that any image resource will be scaled. But gif image is not getting scaled.

Comment: Can you please clarify? (a) I assume you're creating this programmatically. Can you provide code? (b) What is the contentMode for the UIImageView?; (c) when you say not getting scaled properly on Retina device, are you saying that it does not appear to be grabbing the @2x image? So does it look like it does on non-retina display, but a little more pixelated? I don't quite get what you mean when you say "not getting scaled properly"?

Comment: Actually i got the pin point i was doing it programmatically. and still i didnt got solution. I am using UIImage to display image instead of UIImageView. In this case my GIF image is not getting scaled properly.

Comment: JFYI, I am showing GIF in UIView extended class.

Comment: If you're not using UIImageView, but rather some "extended UIView class", then there's no way any of us can help you unless you share the salient portions of that code with us. I hope there's a really compelling reason you're not using UIImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, GIF image scaling is not supported on iPhone Device. Please try the above discussion code for answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with single frame **1.gif** image and also kept **1@2x.gif** in resource folder. It display correct image in iPhone 4s and iPhone 3GS.

I think the problem is in the image. Try to create images with Photoshop and then test it.

Comment: Hi Maulik, You are correct as far as when you use UIImageView, but i am using UIImage to display it. Also important thing is this is specific when i change image from PNG to GIF programmatically. At this time scaling is not proper.

Comment: JFYI, i am using UIView extended class for showing GIF image.

Comment: Hello Maulik, i have checked your answer with xcode and its not working at all. Just try this : Take same image 1.gif with yellow color in it. and 1@2x.gif with blue color. and then build this in Non-retina and Retina device this should work... But it does NOT.... But just change the extension to PNG ..... IT WORKS FINE....

Comment: @DShah: True I am using image view and already both images are different 1.gif and 1@2x.gif.... !!!